# Learning Fundamental Lighting Concepts?

Tags: lighting

What are the best resources you have come across (preferably online, but books too) that could help new photographers come to a better understanding of fundamental lighting concepts?

I’m especially interested in example based learning, where an author uses visuals to demonstrate practical lighting concepts and techniques.

This could be in relation to studio portrait lighting, the use of natural light, indoor, outdoor, flash or strobe photography, still life, macro, etc... Anywhere lighting is of primary concern, so really all aspects of photography.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Online your best resource is the [strobist blog](http://strobist.blogspot.com/) and associated [flickr group](http://www.flickr.com/groups/strobist/) (people posting to the pool are required to describe the lighting setup, so there are examples a-plenty, people often post setup shots and diagrams too).

In print, a very good text on lighting fundamentals is ["Light Science and Magic"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240802756). It takes you through the basics with easy to follow examples and diagrams.

Other useful online resources:

http://speedliting.com

http://www.zarias.com/white-seamless-tutorial-part-1-gear-space/

[Also see the answer to this question.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3818/starting-with-strobes)

Comment: +1, I've got "Light Science and Magic" and it's an extremely good resource.