# Can I trigger a EOS 70D remotely using a 600EX-RT speedlite?

Tags: canon, off-camera-flash, remote

Hi is it possible to remotely trigger an EOS 70D using a 600EX-RT? For example, I'd like the EOS onboard flash to be the slave and the 600EX-RT to be the master.

Comment: Hm, this sound very odd for me. Camera (and internal flash) should be master as camera shoot, not flash. Do you have special reason to want it?

Comment: @RomeoNinov this is a feature of the Canon RT flash protocol: a signal can be sent to one or more (2012-or-later) Canon camera's hotshoe(s) to trigger the shutter(s). See: [Remote camera firing with the Speedlite 600EX-RT and Speedlite Transmitter ST-E3-RT](http://www.learn.usa.canon.com/resources/articles/2013/remote_camera_firing_speedlite600exrt.htmlp)

Comment: Wow the link to the article (See above) by Rudy Winston seems to answer the question. To all you Guys a big thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**No, you have to have another RT unit on the camera hotshoe** to use the remote shutter release capability of Canon's 2012-and-later cameras.  The built-in flash cannot work for this, as it has no RF capability--only optical (i.e., it blinks out light signals, but can't blip out/receive radio signals).

It might be easier to just get cheap radio triggers to be your shutter release, or a Yongnuo YN-E3-RT/YN-600EX-RT.

Comment: As far as I remember 70D can be wireless (not optical) master. Unfortunately at the moment I can't fine the page in documentation where i read this

Comment: Page 200 in the manual

Comment: Optical *is* wireless, but it isn't *wireless RF (radio frequency)* which is how the 600EX-RT communicates.

Comment: @RomeoNinov All [Page 200](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300011965/02/eos70d-im2-en.pdf#page=200) says is that the 70D can do wireless flash, either radio or optical--easy to mistake that for meaning the 70D's built-in flash. Canon's documentation on using wireless flash doesn't help. But the pop-up flashes in all the camera bodies are **optical** masters for wireless (communication is done via flash bursts). I covered some of the Canon optical vs. RT wireless flash differences in [this answer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/56795/27440).

Comment: As stated above this article http://www.learn.usa.canon.com/resources/articles/2013/remote_camera_firing_speedlite600exrt.htmlp seems to answer the question. I just need to put it to the test.

Comment: @Fred, just make sure you note the bit in that article that goes: "...if you have _one_ compatible EOS camera with [a 600EX-RT or ST-E3-RT] mounted, you can take **another** 600EX-RT “slave unit” off-camera and fire the camera by pressing a single button on the flash in your hand." I.e., your popup flash can't be used for this.

Comment: I ordered an ST-E3-RT which came today so have been able to check out the function together with a 600EX-RT Speedlite Flash. Have been trying to get them to function for the past 2 hrs and purely by some freak stroke of luck finally had success.  Once I have figured out tomorrow what the exact settings were required I will post back.