# Will a Yongnou YN600EX-RT flash work with a Canon 700D using radio control?

Tags: flash, dslr, yongnuo, canon-700d

Will a YN600EX-RT Flash work with a canon 700D using radio control? If yes, how can I set them?

Answer (score 3):

The YN600EX-RT is fully compatible with all current and recent Canon EOS bodies going back for at least 10-15 years. This would include all EOS bodies that are "Type A" and E-TTL II compatible.

However, as of August 03, 2016 none of those bodies have built-in radio transmitters. To use a YN600EX-RT off camera you need either another RT flash (e.g. YN600EX-RT, 430EX III-RT, etc.) or a radio based flash controller (e.g. ST-E3-RT, YN-E3-RT, etc.) to communicate via wireless radio with your YN600EX-RT.

Previous Canon flashes that don't have an "RT" in the name use an optical communication system to communicate from the camera to the flash. The built in flash on your 700D can optically control a compatible optically controlled flash such as the 580EX II or YN568EX II. But it can not control the YN600EX-RT because that flash doesn't have the capability to receive those optical pulses.

Answer (score 1):

> Will a YN600EX-RT flash work with a Canon 700D using radio control?

With an appropriate RT master unit on the camera's hotshoe, absolutely. Without additional gear, no. The 700D has no built-in radio master; its pop-up flash is only [an optical master](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56790/is-there-a-canon-equivalent-of-the-nikon-cls).

RT master units include:

- Canon 600EX-RT, Canon 600EX II-RT
- Canon 430EX III-RT
- Canon ST-E3-RT
- Phottix Laso transmitter for Canon
- Yongnuo YN-E3-RT
- Yongnuo YN-600EX-RT