# How to fire a Pentax AF 360 FGZ flash with a canon 7D camera

Tags: canon, pentax, canon-7d

I have a Pentax AF 360 FGZ flash and a Canon 7D camera. Different hardware I know. But I want to be able to fire the flash, possibly using a remote trigger that would allow me to remotely take the shot and fire the flash as well.

Comment: Since you can not take advantage of all the built-in automation of that pentax flash, I would sell it and buy a cheaper, more powerful, manual flash like the Yongnuo YN-560.

Comment: Is it possible to use the wireless mode and fire it as slave?

Comment: I would love to be able to use the wireless mode. As far as I remember, AF360 is wireless

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the wireless P-TTL "smart" optical triggering with Pentax gear, the AF 360 FGZ has a "dumb" optical slave mode (Slave 2) built-in that works with any simple flash burst (read: will work with any brand camera gear). Set the 7D's pop-up flash into M mode (to avoid sending out an eTTL pre-flash), and it should trigger the AF 360 to fire in sync. You will, of course, have all the range/line of sight issues that optical slaving does.  But you don't have to buy radio triggers to use this flash off-camera with your 7D.

[From this pentaxforums post](http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/125-flashes-lighting-studio/226522-af-360-af500-slave-flash.html#post2404872), to place the flash into the "dumb" optical slave mode:

> Set the switch on the right side in the upper position.
>
> Hold "light" button down for 2 seconds.
>
> Press the "S" (select) button to toggle between Slave 1 (Wireless P-TTL) mode and Slave 2 (Optical dumb slave) mode.
>
> Press "light" button to accept and exit.

Any flash burst (even one from a P&S) should trigger the flash remotely.

To get the camera shutter to operate remotely, however, you do need a shutter remote of some kind (cable release, radio triggers, or an infrared remote) as a separate signal. You can only trip the camera shutter via the camera hotshoe with Canon RT remote-flash gear (e.g., 600EX-RTs).

See also: [What should I look for in a wireless flash trigger for a home studio?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57653/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-wireless-flash-trigger-for-a-home-studio)

Comment: Be aware that the AF360FGZ will go back to TTL mode when it powers off. This will be annoying if you want to use it in dumb-slave mode all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could pick up a set of [cheap radio triggers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002W3IXZW), or you could take [David Hobby's advice](http://strobist.blogspot.com/2010/02/its-time-for-pc-jack-to-die.html) and use some 1/8" adapters and a long cable with male 1/8" connectors on each end.

Comment: Will the radio trigger be able to fire the camera as well? or it is just a way of firing the flash when the camera's button is pressed

Comment: The ones I linked just makes the flash fire at an appropriate time, but there are triggers that can work as remote shutter releases too -- they just cost more. Here's a description of [how to use PocketWizard triggers to do that](http://wiki.pocketwizard.com/index.php?title=Remote_Camera_Triggering).