# How can I tell if a Yongnuo RF-603 II will work with my flash from my flash's specs?

Tags: off-camera-flash, yongnuo, wireless-flash, compatibility

I'm going to buy Yongnuo RF-603 II, but I'm confused. Will it work with my flash, a Shanny SN600N ([specs here](http://www.szshanny.com/en/products-18.html)) or not?

Comment: Define "work" for you? What level of functionality? Anything beyond telling the flash to fire?

Comment: Might work better as a StackExchange question and less as a shopping question if you _completely_ genericized to "how can I tell if a trigger works with my flash?" and then detailed what you mean by "works". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yongnuo's RF603II triggers are manual-only, so they will work to fire any flash that has [an ISO-compliant foot](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/DigiCam/User-Guide/FZ-10/Ext-Flash/Basic-Functions.html), with the firing pin in the center of the foot's "square".  You probably can't tell this from the specs, but you will be able to tell by pictures of the flash's foot.

The Shanny SN600N has that, so it will fire in sync remote if you have one RF-603II as a transmitter on your camera, and another one on the flash's foot to act as a receiver.  It has no built-in radio receiver.

But. With these triggers, it will only fire in sync. You will not have TTL, FP/HSS, or remote power/zoom/groups/settings control over the flash.  All you can do is fire the flash remotely and wake it up remotely if it goes to sleep.

See also:

- [What are the Yongnuo flash naming conventions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47702/what-are-the-yongnuo-flash-naming-conventions)
- [What features should one look for when selecting a flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17722/what-features-should-one-look-for-when-selecting-a-flash)
- [What does an expensive flash unit buy over a cheap one?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/33842/what-does-an-expensive-flash-unit-buy-over-a-cheap-one)
- [What should I look for in a wireless flash trigger for a home studio?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57653/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-wireless-flash-trigger-for-a-home-studio)

Comment: Got my answer, thanks to @inkista i just have one more question if i buy this i've to work with it manually right? I just want single flash to fire like off-camera flash does or should i go for another yongnuo unit?

Comment: @AliMukhtar, I think the Yongnuo flash naming conventions Q&A should answer your question. Please read that first. If it doesn't, then please post  a separate question. SE is more of a Q&A database than a discussion board. We do things a little differently around here. Please see [the tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour); also, IMO? Go Godox, not Yongnuo. :)